# Convert docx to PDF

Tags: windows, linux, pdf, docx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PDF creation software, for docx and odt](https://superuser.com/questions/134783/PDF-creation-software-for-docx-and-odt)

How can I convert docx files to PDF format .Please give applications in both Linux and Windows platform

Comment: Microsoft Word 2007 and later (that is, all versions of Word that save in the .docx format) have a built-in "Create PDF" feature. This is *the* way!

Answer (score 11):

[OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/) will open .docx and export to PDF. It runs on Linux and Windows.

Comment: +1 for the simplest and more suited method

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MS Office 2007 to create the DOCX files that you wish to convert to PDFs, then I would definitely recommend using the native conversion feature. If you cannot already Save As PDF, then download the plug-in from Microsoft here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&displaylang=en

If you are looking to do this in Linux, or to perform the conversion in the same manner on both Windows and Linux, OpenOffice.org is a great program for this. It is a full-featured office suite that has included the Export to PDF feature for quite some time:
notspam-http://www.openoffice.org/

If you are looking to do this as a batch, it looks like you're in the realm of commercial software specifically for this purpose. One list to look at:
notspam-http://www.fileguru.com/downloads/docx_to_pdf

Answer (score 2):

Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333459/convert-a-docx-document-to-pdf-as-a-service

Answer (score 2):

Try one of those:
1) Newer versions of OpenOffice open DOCX. So open it with OpenOffice Writer and export to PDF.
2) Install a PDF printer, like PDFCreator or PDF995. Then open DOCX (if you have M$ Office or OpenOffice) and print to PDF.
3) If you do not have installed programs to open DOCX, try uploading it to Google Docs (use "convert" option) and see it there because some documents are not correctly converted. Then download as PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are looking for a programmatic approach, but if you are then you may want to have a look at this [PDF Conversion Web Service](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html) that can be used from any Web Services capable environment including Java and .NET. It supports watermarking as well.

Note that I worked on this project so the usual disclaimers apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.bullzip.com/ PDFPrinter to print the docx file from MS Word to a PDF File.

Answer (score 1):

You can use openoffice 3 (on Windows and Linux) or Microsoft office 2007 (Windows) or later. Openoffice also comes up with pyuno bridge which helps you to automate the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a quick tool or automated process to do it for you? Or are you actually looking for some code to achieve it?

If you are looking for a tool, then [this google search](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=convert+docx+to+pdf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) is quite enlightening. If you are looking for code then you are going to have to be more detailed - don't just ask for the code because this is not rent-a-coder.